# Need to create notification like Facebook using SignalR

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I am beginer with SignalR. My website is developing with ASP.NET MVC5
I am trying to create a live notification like Facebook, everybody advise I should use SignalR.

I tried to use SignalR with sample code at here http://techbrij.com/database-change-notifications-asp-net-signalr-sqldependency but unfortunately, my hosting admin said that they can not Grant subscribe permission for my sql user so I can not do like this tip.

Do you have any advise for me to using SignalR without subscribe permission? I only need :

- The count of number notifications
- The content of notification will be
  show like Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having SQL notify when updates happens do it from the domain. Use a `EventAggregator`

like https://www.nuget.org/packages/Caliburn.Micro.EventAggregator/

from your repository or other place were you update the database do

```
public void UpdateFoo(Foo foo) 
{
   ... //Update here
   this.eventAggregator.Publish(new UpdatedEvent<Foo>(foo);
}
```

You can use my library if you want to seamless forward these events to the clients

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/wiki

Comment: Do i need any permission on my Database?

Comment: Its not database related, instead of using the Database you fire a event on the place in your domain were you update the database

Comment: I need store the notification also, so i create a table name Notification to store all notification because some user does not read their notification immediately